# Type "is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint" when destructuring generic

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I've Googled this scenario but couldn't find an answer relevant to my situation. What I am trying to do is have a function add properties to an object defined in a generic type. I then want to destructure those extra properties and supply a `Record` with the user's properties to a function. I understand what the error *means* but cannot figure out why it applies to my situation. `T` never changes, so why is using the `Omit` helper creating this error? (To clarify, the `Omit` type is used by Typescript when defining types from destructuring)

I've reproduced the error with the following code:

```js
type Foo<T extends Record<any, any> = Record<any, never>> = {
  key: string;
} & T;

function func<T extends Record<any, any> = Record<any, never>>(
  arg0: Foo<T>,
  arg1: (props?: T) => any
) {
  const { key, ...props } = arg0;
  arg1(props);
}
```

Comment: Your repro is equivalent to this https://tsplay.dev/NB4lVW which is indicative that maybe there is something missing. If you want to keep it as is, this would work for you https://tsplay.dev/mbKz3W. I can't explain why what you wrote doesn't work, maybe because you were inferring T from a function argument, which is contravariant

Comment: I believe it isn't working because in `func`, `T` could be a type which explicitly defines has a key `key`, so omitting it could cause the object to no longer be of type `T`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `func` `arg1:(props?:T)` is not the same as the destructured props-object in `const {key,...props}=arg0`because you are omitting the key `key` from `arg0` by destructing.

Consider the following input for T:
`type SomeType = { key:"abc, data:any }`
`arg1` will expect something like `arg1: (props?: { key:"abc, data:any }) => any` but `arg1` will NEVER receive an object with `key` as a key because you are omitting `key` with your destructuring. `arg1` will receive `(props?: {  data:any }) => any`. So `T !== props(dest.)` when T itself contains the key `key`.

To make it work you just have to adjust the type annotation of arg1 like this.

```
type Foo<T extends Record<any, any> = Record<any, never>> = {
    key: string;
} & T;

function func<T extends Record<any, any> = Record<any, never>>(
    arg0: Foo<T>,
    arg1: (props?: Omit<T, "key">) => any
) {
    const { key, ...props } = arg0;
    arg1(props);
//OR
    arg1(arg0);
}
```

Comment: Yep, this was it. I created a type `U` that is equal to `{ key: string }`, and used `Omit` with `keyof U` to do this without writing out all the properties.